# User adding correct answers with links to own site

Tags: discussion, answers

I've noticed a user who at the end of [61](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2888956%20is%3Aanswer%20url%3Aphponwebsites) of [68](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2888956%20is%3Aanswer) answers leaves a link to the same site for further information. The link is relevant to the question. However, several of the answers were added to old questions that already had selected answers, and do not add anything new to the selected answer.

Update: There seems to be another user doing the same: [160](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Aphponwebsites+user%3A2552725) of [185](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2552725/guru?tab=answers) answers

What action should I take?

Comment: At least one of the questions they supplied an answer to had previously [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20235071/73226) to the same site that had been moderator deleted. From a different user who seems even [more prolific](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2552725+is%3Aanswer+url%3Aphponwebsites) in spamming that link.

Comment: Yeah. I've done a search for answers with phponwebsites.com [246  total answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Aphponwebsites) : [4 accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Aphponwebsites+is%3Aanswer+isaccepted%3Ayes).

Comment: And 241 of those 246 were contributed by just three users. With [John](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3259677++is%3Aanswer+url%3Aphponwebsites) being the third one (20/23)

Comment: if you see any suspicious activity, raise a custom flag

Comment: A fine line ... I created a concise set of Help documents from an otherwise inpenetrable source. So, when I answer a question on that topic, I *may* refer to my on-line documents. However, personally I draw the line at adding an answer (and link) when there already is a good one. And I will never [hunt down 2-year old AND answered questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9181141/2564301).

Comment: I've flagged one answer for both of the users. The most prolific account (Guru) is no longer available.

Comment: @Jongware they are consistently using their own reference when a canonical one is available.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Yeah, this looks like a coordinated attempt to promote a specific website. I've either edited the link out (where there was some unique redeeming value in the answer) or deleted the answer (where they copied someone else's answer from years before just to spam that link). Both accounts have been warned, and it's pretty clear they have attempted this before.

If they spam this link on one more answer, I will destroy their accounts and feed them into the anti-spam system. They've been thoroughly warned.

Thanks for the flags.

Comment: the tone reminds me: [*say "what" one more time* (warning: strong language, violence)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RtXF2j5JAds) :)

Comment: I now have the picture of the 'anti-spam system' as being something really horrid, rather like the shredder in Gremlins 2...

Comment: ... or the wood shredding machine from (the film) *Fargo*.